# "failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module X" when call method from variable which represents item that impl trait

Tags: rust

I have a function which takes vector of objects which implements some trait. I want to use it like next:

```
trait SomeTrait {
    fn trait_function() {
        println!("Rust works !");
    }
}

struct MyStruct {}
impl SomeTrait for MyStruct {}

fn test(items: Vec<impl SomeTrait>) {
    for item in items {
        item::trait_function();
    }
}

fn main () {
    test(vec![MyStruct{}, MyStruct{}]);
}
```

but when I run this code I got an error:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `item`
  --> src/main.rs:12:9
   |
12 |         item::trait_function();
   |         ^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `item`
```

this is [minimal sandbox implementation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=818ff33f18b337cb9a52d439f3fb1028).

Could somebody explain how to dynamically call function from variable, which represents impl item ?

Comment: `trait_function()` does not take any parameters. Did you mean to add a `&self`  parameter or similar? If so, just add it and replace the `::` with a `.`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I wanted to keep it static. So I thought maybe it possible to call it like `Self::trait_function()` but from external

Comment: Instead of `impl SomeTrait`, use an explicit type parameter: `fn test<T: SomeTrait>(items: Vec<T>)` then you can do `T::trait_function()`.

Comment: @eggyal the difference that each struct that implements trait can have own implementation of provided methods. So how can I use then appropriate method related to specific struct then ? This is sandbox implementation which reproduces the issue: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=65c7413b0ccc46c6744568be9b782d7d

Comment: @eggyal I just want to say that's why I use `Vec<impl Trait>` instead

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo note that the items in `Vec<impl Trait>` must all have the same type anyway. If you want them to be able to have different types, you need a `dyn` reference (e.g. `Vec<&dyn Trait>` or `Vec<Box<dyn Trait>>`).

Comment: ^^^ what @Jmb just said, except to add that because `trait_function` is an associated fn without a `&self` or `&mut self` receiver argument, `SomeTrait` is not object-safe and you *cannot* create `dyn SomeTrait` trait objects.  So you can't have such a vector at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call a static method of `impl Trait`. You have to use a named generic parameter:

```rust
fn test<T: Trait>(items: Vec<T>) {
    for item in items {
        T::trait_function();
    }
}
```

However, from the comments it seems what you really want is `dyn Trait`.